# Issue staring docker container with nginx and passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, passenger

I am getting this weird issue in my docker container when I try to starting it. The container is trying to run a rails 4 app on Fedora 23 using nginx and passenger, but I am using the package ulyaoth-nginx-passenger5 that install nginx already build with passenger.

This configuration is working right outside the container in a VPS.

The message is:
nginx: [alert] could not open the passenger log file for writing during Nginx startup, some log lines might be lost (will retry from Passenger core) (2: No such file or directory)

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
[vns@localhost logica-erp]$ docker run -p 80:80 -d --name logica-erp peopleware/logica-erp 
e18235436c7c57081fc7520f19913a39be6026f82f23697fdd831f5b3acd563f
Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
[vns@localhost logica-erp]$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
[vns@localhost logica-erp]$ docker start -i logica-erp 
nginx: [alert] could not open the passenger log file for writing during Nginx startup, some log lines might be lost (will retry from Passenger core) (2: No such file or directory)
```

You can check the docker file here:
https://gist.github.com/victorsosa/7fe84b94d6f525021ac1f783adddf86b

Comment: Can you post your nginx, app, and passenger configs as well? It sounds like your nginx configuration probably runs nginx as a user other than `app` and can't write to the `/home/app`.

Comment: yes, as nginx user; check the (https://gist.github.com/victorsosa/7a3ac305a3cb7944a1bfe5efbe493b0d)

Comment: I tested changing the user to app and I got the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the last command to:

```
CMD nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```